# Project no longer compiles after recent Android Studio update AGP 8.0

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors, android-jetpack-compose

I built a tip calculator app in Jetpack Compose and after the recent update to AGP 8.0 it no longer will compile giving me configuration errors.

Top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

build.gradle with dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'edu.qc.seclass.tipcalculatoractivity'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.qc.seclass.tipcalculatoractivity"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
}
```

which gave this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.7.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.7.0
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.7.0 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.7.0 available for offline mode.
```

I made some changes I found online to try and fix the problem but nothing seemed to work. I've converted everything back to original code now though.

Answer (score 0):

@TheMasian

Try to update kotlin plugin on project `build.gradle` to the latest version:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
```

And compiler extension on app `build.gradle`:

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
    }
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#groovy) you can find more about the major update of AGP for this year.

Hope it helps.